# SVG masks without defs or use

Tags: xml, svg, frontend

I want to render a masked shape in an SVG without using `defs` or `use` tags.

I have an svg with the following markup...

```
<defs>
  <mask id="mask-2" stroke-width="4" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="35" height="19" fill="white">
    <rect id="path-1" x="0" y="0" width="35" height="19" rx="3" stroke-width="4"></rect>
  </mask>
  <mask id="mask-4" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="5" height="17" fill="white">
    <rect id="path-3" x="1" y="1" width="5" height="17"></rect>
  </mask>
  <mask id="mask-6" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="5" height="17" fill="white">
    <rect id="path-5" x="9" y="1" width="5" height="17"></rect>
  </mask>
  <mask id="mask-8" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="5" height="17" fill="white">
    <rect id="path-7" x="17" y="1" width="5" height="17"></rect>
  </mask>
  <mask id="mask-10" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="5" height="17" fill="white">
    <rect id="path-9" x="25" y="1" width="5" height="17"></rect>
  </mask>
</defs>

<g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
  <g className="sock-top" transform="translate(21.000000, 0.000000)" stroke="#AAAAAA">
    <use mask="url(#mask-2)" stroke-width="4" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
    <use mask="url(#mask-4)" stroke-width="2" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
    <use mask="url(#mask-6)" stroke-width="2" xlink:href="#path-5"></use>
    <use mask="url(#mask-8)" stroke-width="2" xlink:href="#path-7"></use>
    <use mask="url(#mask-10)" stroke-width="2" xlink:href="#path-9"></use>
  </g>
</g>
```

I'm trying to avoid using `defs`. Is it possible to use masks without doing so?

I was hoping I could simply replace -

```
<use mask="url(#mask-2)" stroke-width="4" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
```

with

```
<mask id="mask-2" stroke-width="4" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="35" height="19" fill="white">
  <rect id="path-1" x="0" y="0" width="35" height="19" rx="3" stroke-width="4"></rect>
</mask>
```

but nothing renders when I do so.

Is this possible?

Comment: defs is optional but recommended. You can omit it. You could turn the mask into a data uri and embed it that way. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme